# Como valido una cedula o numero de identidad personal EN PHP?

Tags: php

tengo una práctica con un formulario en Php el cual debe validar el 
    DNI o Cédula y el correo de usuario que se está registrando al momento de 
    ser digitado e ingresarlos si no están registrados en la base de datos.

Tengo la tabla simpatizante en MySQL con los campos, cedula, nombre, 
    recinto, mesa, correo, contacto, dirección, recomendado.
    Luego de realizar la conexión a bd.

EL código es.

```
if (cedula != null) && (correo != null) {

$sql="INSERT INTO simpatizantes 
VALUES
('".$_POST["cedula"]."',
'".$_POST["nombre"]."',
'".$_POST["recinto"]."',
'".$_POST["mesa"]."',
'".$_POST["correo"]."',
'".$_POST["contacto"]."',
'".$_POST["direccion"]."',
'".$_POST["recomendado"]."' 
)";     
}else if 
    {echo "Favor introducir una Cédula o Correo valido";}
```

No me realiza la comparacion y el codigo da errores que no entiendo.

Comment: pon los errores, otra cosa es que posiblemente si mandas eso por un formulario y lo que estás haciendo es mandar cédula por post, entonces lo envía como cadena vacía, no como null

Comment: Ocupas mysqli o PDO?

Comment: Ocupo Mysqli, aun no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes agregar el POST que realizas, adicional asegurate que las variables
"`cedula`" y correo le asignes de manera correcta los valores

```
$cedula = $_POST["cedula"];
```

Trata de incluir las comparaciones dentro de un mismo () y en "`else`" quita el `If`  porque en realidad esta de más.

```
if (($cedula != null) && ($correo != null)) {
.... } else { echo "Favor introducir una Cédula o Correo valido"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para validar si ya el NIT o CEDULA se encuentra en la tabla de la base de datos has esta consulta:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("ip // host","user mysql","pass mysql","db mysql");
$q = $mysqli->query("SELECT cedula FROM simpatizantes WHERE cedula = '".$_POST['cedula']."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($q)>0){

echo "Esta cedula ya esta guardada";

}else{

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO simpatizantes (cedula,nombre,recinto,mesa,correo,contacto,direccion,recomendado) VALUES ('".$_POST['cedula']."','".$_POST['nombre']."','".$_POST['recinto']."','".$_POST['mesa']."','".$_POST['correo']."','".$_POST['contacto']."','".$_POST['direccion']."','".$_POST['recomendado']."'");
echo "Registros salvados en la base de datos";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar tanto el correo como la cédula de la siguiente manera:

```
 <?php
  //Declaración de variables:
 $cedula = $correo = "";
 $cedulaErr = $correroErr = "";
  //bandera para validar
 $valid = true;
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

 if (empty($_POST["cedula"])) {
    $cedulaErr = "La cédula es obligatoria.";
    $valid = false;
 } else {
    $sqlCedula = "SELECT cedula FROM simpatizantes WHERE cedula = '$cedula'";
    //Acá haces la validación usando sentencias preparadas con mysqli o PDO si la cédula ya está registrada.
    //Pon $valid = false; si existe, de lo contrario $valid = true; si NO existe.
}

 if (empty($_POST["correo"])) {
    $correroErr = "El correo es obligatorio.";
    $valid = false;
 } else {
    $correo = test_input($_POST["correo"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($correo, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $correroErr = "Formato de correo no válido.";
        $valid = false;
    }
    $sqlCorreo = "SELECT correo FROM simpatizantes WHERE correo = '$correo'";
    //Acá haces la validación usando sentencias preparadas  con mysqli o PDO si el correo ya está registrado.
    //Pon $valid = false; si existe, de lo contrario $valid = true; si NO existe.
}

if ($valid) {//Si todo está validado y sanitizado, que ejecute el INSERT
    $sql = "INSERT INTO simpatizantes 
 VALUES
 ('" . $_POST["cedula"] . "',
 '" . $_POST["nombre"] . "',
 '" . $_POST["recinto"] . "',
 '" . $_POST["mesa"] . "',
 '" . $_POST["correo"] . "',
 '" . $_POST["contacto"] . "',
 '" . $_POST["direccion"] . "',
 '" . $_POST["recomendado"] . "' 
  )";
    //Acá pon el código msqli o PDO para ejecutar el INSERT
   }
  }

  //Muestras mensajes de error si los hay:
 if($cedulaErr != ""){
   echo $cedulaErr;
 }
if($correroErr != ""){
 echo $correroErr;
}
```

> Es imperativo sanitizar los valores que vienen del POST, así como también usar sentencias preparadas ya sea con msqli o PDO.